# Returning a dependent pair from a foreign function

Tags: ffi, idris, idris2

I have the following Chez support file:

```lisp
(define list-copy-with-length (xs)
  (cons (length xs) (list-copy xs)))
```

and I have this Idris file:

```
%foreign "scheme,chez:list-copy-with-length"
prim__listToVect : List t -> (Nat, Vect n t)

listToVect : List t -> (n ** Vect n t)
listToVect ls =
  let (n, vs) = prim__listToVect ls
  in MkDPair n vs
```

Naturally, type-checking fails on this code, because the compiler does not know that the `n` defined in the `let` expression is the same as the `n` in the return type of `listToVect`.

I tried a few guesses at using `believe_me` to fix this, but I wasn't able to figure it out. Is it possible to define a function like this? What is the correct way to do it, without incurring significant runtime cost of recursively re-computing the length (as in `Data.Vect.filter`)?

Here is one such guess:

```
listToVect : {t : _} -> {n : _} -> List t -> (n ** Vect n t)
listToVect ls =
  let (n', vs) = prim__listToVect ls
      itsEqualDamnit : Equal n' n = believe_me ()
  in rewrite itsEqualDamnit in MkDPair n vs
```

Ideally I'd like to entirely avoid unpacking the pair anyway, because (at least in the Chez backend), pairs and depdendent pairs are both represented identically as cons cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`believe_me` is already an unsafe cast. Just... cast the `Vect`?

```
%foreign "scheme,chez:list-copy-with-length"
prim__listToVect : List t -> (Nat, Vect n t)

listToVect : List t -> (n ** Vect n t)
listToVect ls =
  let (n, vs) = prim__listToVect {n = 0} ls
  in  MkDPair n (believe_me vs)
```

Your Scheme code is wrong: `define`'s syntax is not like that and `list-copy-to-vect` needs three arguments, since `prim__listToVect` has three arguments (`t`, `n`, and a `List t`). Note that I pass a dummy in for `n` on the Idris side.

```lisp
(define (list-copy-with-length t n xs) (cons (length xs) (list-copy xs)))
```

You can be even more direct by pairing this Scheme definition

```lisp
(define (idris-prim-listToVect t xs) (cons (length xs) (list-copy xs)))
```

With this Idris

```
%foreign "scheme,chez:idris-prim-listToVect"
prim__listToVect : List t -> (Nat, List t)

listToVect : List t -> (n ** Vect n t)
listToVect xs = believe_me (prim__listToVect xs)
```

(This works since, as you noted, a `DPair` is represented the same as a normal pair and `List` is represented the same as a `Vect`.)

Comment: Good catch on the Scheme errors, I usually write Common Lisp and I always get the syntax mixed up :) I also didn't realize that the implicit should be arguments to the primitive function, which makes a lot of sense in hindsight. I did try casting the Vect, but I still got an error about and unsolved hole. It was probably coming from one of the other errors that you pointed out.